# Tomcat server not starting. in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to host my web app through Tomcat. I am using the Spring framework and have Tomcat set up. I have converted it to a Maven project and one a Maven file and moved the war file to correct webapps folder in the Tomcat installation folder. When I try to run, it gives the me the error:

```
Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

In the console, I see that it gets stuck on

```
Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

I am using an MySQL database and in the MySQL workbench it says the server is running. I am really confused as to why this is happening. I have even tried the following:

```
Click on Window > Show view > Server OR right click on the server in "Servers" view, select "Properties".
In the "General" panel, click on the "Switch Location" button.
The "Location: [workspace metadata]" should replace by something else.
Open the Overview screen for the server by double clicking it.
In the Server locations tab , select "Use Tomcat location".
Save the configurations and restart the Server.
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Servers Tab from Windows>Show View>Servers menu.
2. Right click on the server and delete it.
3. Create a new server by going New>Server on Server Tab.
4. Click on “Configure runtime environments…” link.
5. Select the Apache Tomcat v7.0 server and remove it. This will remove the Tomcat server configuration. This is where many people do mistake – they remove the server but do not remove the Runtime environment.
6. Click on OK and exit the screen above now.
7. From the screen below, choose Apache Tomcat v7.0 server and click on next button.
8. Browse to Tomcat Installation Directory.
9. Click on Next and choose which project you would like to deploy.
10. Click on Finish after Adding your project.
11. Now launch your server. This will fix your Server timeout or any issues with old server configuration. This solution can also be used to fix “port update not being taking place” issues.

Source: [Fix Tomcat](http://sansatechnology.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/how-to-fix-eclipse-tomcat-not-starting-in-45-seconds/)

Answer (score 1):

the server requires more time to start but the default start time limit is `45 seconds` .

All you have to do is open the servers tab, right click on your server and click open , a menu will be opened in your editor , open submenu `Timeouts` and change the value of `Start (in seconds)` to a higher value for example 300 seconds. and start your server again.

Comment: did you save the file before restarting tomcat  ? is 45s in the log?

Comment: Yeah I saved it. I believe the log is with 45s but I tried putting 400s and still didnt

Answer (score 0):

**In my case, the problem came from an impossible loopback on localhost.**

Tomcat effectively started (I could call "http://localhost:8080/myApp"), but Eclipse didn't get a response of that and it considered Tomcat keep on starting.

A software called ZScaler (set by admin to protect the enterprise) on Windows 10 put loopback restrictions. Fortunately, an option existed to disable loopback restrictions on ZScaler.

A VPN may cause the same restrictions.

If you don't find which application cause the trouble, you can change "Host name" in Eclipse's Tomcat General Informations, from "localhost" to "yourIP" (ex : 179.25.14.178), BUT this trick won't allow DEBUG MODE.